# Swap string in c

Tags: c, string, swap

i have a little problem, i'can't swap my string i have error bus and i can use only while fonction ft_strrev. I think it's because my string can't stop.
Ty

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *ft_strrev(char *str)
{
    int i;
    int a;
    int temp;

    i = 0;
    a = 0;

    while(str[a] != '\0')
    {
        a++;
    }

    printf ("%i\n", a);

    while(i < a  / 2 && a < 0)
    {
        temp = str[a - i - 1];
        str[a - i - 1] = str[i];
        str[i]= temp;
        i++;
        printf ("%c\n", str[i]);
    }
    return (str);
}

int main()
{
    printf("TestString");
    printf("%s", ft_strrev("TestString"));
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to reverse a *string literal*.

Comment: Try `printf("%s", ft_strrev(strdup("TestString")));` for fun and profit (note: leaks memory; if your environment knows `strdupa()`, better use that.)

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't have the problem you describe. See [mcve] in the [help], and be sure to post the real code, and a real description of the problem.

Comment: @user3386109 The posted code is invoking UB

Comment: @EugeneSh. No it doesn't. You didn't read the whole thing, and have come to a hasty conclusion. My guess is that the OP had a version of the code that invoked UB, but that's not the code that the OP posted. The "verifiable" part of [mcve] was overlooked/ignored by the OP.

Comment: @user3386109 Ah.. I guess you mean the `a < 0` part.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yup, but I was hoping to make the OP work for his supper :)

Comment: @user3386109 I hope it will remove the confusion from the future commentators :)

Comment: If you fix your swap logic, `printf("%s\n", ft_strrev((char[]){"TestString"}));` would work. (e.g. using a *compound-literal* instead of a *string-literal*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cannot pass the *string literal* `"TestString"` to `ft_strrev`, in C99+, you can pass a *compound literal*, e.g. `(char[]){"TestString"}`.

A *string literal*, e.g. `"TestString"` is created in **read-only** memory (generally in the `.rodata` section of an executable) Any attempt to modify read-only data invoked *Undefined Behavior* as you have found.

A *compound literal*, allows a cast to an array which creates an *array* allowing modification.

In `ft_strrev`, while your loop to get the length of the string is fine, but understand the resulting index -- is the index of the *nul-terminating* character -- which you later attempt to address by *subtracting* `1` throughout the indexes of `str` and `temp` during the swap. Save yourself the grief and simply subtract `1` from `a` before you begin your swap. For example, a convenient place would be:

```
printf ("%i\n", a--);
```

With an index to the first character, and an index to the last character, your loop logic simplifies to:

```
    while (i < a) {
        ...
        i++, a--;
    }
```

(you can also simply use a pointers to the first and last characters instead of array indexes -- but that is completely up to you)

Simplifying things and adding a couple of `'\n'` to your format strings so your output isn't all smushed together and so that your program is POSIX compliant (outputting a final `'\n'`), you could do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *ft_strrev(char *str)
{
    int i = 0,
        a = 0;

    while (str[a])
        a++;

    printf ("%i\n", a--);

    while (i < a) {
        char temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[a];
        str[a]= temp;
        i++, a--;
    }

    return str;
}

int main (void)
{
    printf ("TestString\n");
    printf ("%s\n", ft_strrev ((char[]){"TestString"}));

    return 0;
}
```

(you should also check `if (str != NULL)` at the beginning of `ft_strrev`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cmplitrev
TestString
10
gnirtStseT
```

That being said, while a *compound-literal* is 100% fine to use -- it isn't the most readable unless you are familiar with it, so you are better served simply declaring a character array in `main()` and passing the array as an argument to `ft_strrev`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Main mistakes .

First in `while-loop` It should be `a > 0`  you codded `a < 0` .

Second By calling `ft_strrev("TestString")` You pass a **String Constant** Which you cannot edit.This will result a `Segmentation Fault` .So you need to dynamically allocate memory for that.

Solution :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *ft_strrev(char *st)
{
    int i;
    int a;
    char temp, *str;

    str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(st)); // allocating memory.
    strcpy(str, st);                  // copying string.
    i = 0;
    a = 0;

    while (str[a] != '\0')
    {
        a++;
    }

    printf("%i\n", a);

    while (i < a / 2 && a > 0) // not a < 0
    {
        temp = str[a - i - 1];
        str[a - i - 1] = str[i];
        str[i] = temp;
        i++;
        printf("%c\n", str[i]);
    }
    return (str);
}
int main()
{
    printf("TestString");
    printf("%s", ft_strrev("TestString"));
    return (0);
}
```

**Output :-**

```
TestString10
e
s
t
S
S
gnirtStseT
```

Answer (score 0):

> i'can't swap my string i have error bus....

The program that you have posted in your question can not give *Bus error* because of `while` loop condition in function `ft_strrev()`

```
while(i < a  / 2 && a < 0) 
                    ^^^^^
```

The variable `a` is suppose to contain the size of input string "TestString" which is `10` and `10 < 0` will always return `false`. Hence control can never go inside while loop where you are trying to modify the `str` while reversing the input string which is a string literal.

The below answer is based on an assumption that while posting the program in question you have made a typo and the correct condition is `a > 0` instead of `a < 0`.

You program is having an [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you are trying to modify a string literal. You are passing a string literal to function `ft_strrev()`:

```
printf("%s", ft_strrev("TestString"));  // here "TestString" is a string literal
```

and in function `ft_strrev()` while reversing the input string, in the `while` loop block you are trying to modify the input string.

*An undefined behavior includes program may fail to compile, or it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.*

To fix the issue, you can allocate a memory dynamically and copy the string literal to that memory and reverse it. Here you need to take care of free the dynamically allocated memory once you are done with it.

The other solution is initialize a array from the string literal, like this:

```
int main() {
    char arr[] = "TestString"; // initializing array with string literal
    printf("%s\n", arr);
    printf("%s\n", ft_strrev(arr));
    return 0;
}
```

The statement

```
char arr[] = "TestString";
```

is equivalent to

```
char arr[] = {'T','e','s','t','S','t','r','i','n','g','\0'};
```

Also, you don't need to provide the dimension to the array. Based on the initializer, the compiler will automatically set the dimension.

This array `arr` is a local array and you can modify it's value based on your logic to reverse the string.

So, instead of passing string literal directly to `ft_strrev()` function use array in the `main()` *[same as I demonstrated above]* and make correction in the `ft_strrev()` function `while` loop condition

```
while(i < a/2 && a > 0)
```

Try with these two changes. Do let me know if you have any doubts.